# La secuencia no contiene elementos intentando hacer un ListView en XAML

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, listview, xaml

Intentando bindar un ObservableCollection en un ListView me da el siguiente error en la vista:
*La secuencia no contiene ningún elemento.*

La vista es esta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Alvac.Pages.UserPage"
         Title="Alvac"
         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"
         BindingContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout
        BindingContext="{Binding Centros}">
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Centros}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame
                            CornerRadius="20"
                            HasShadow="true"
                            Margin="5">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout 
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label 
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        FontSize="Medium" 
                                        Text="{Binding Descripcion}"
                                        TextColor="Black">
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Spacing="10"
        Padding="8">
        <Label 
            Text="Bienvenid@"
            FontSize="18"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="{StaticResource FontColor}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Y quiero bindar:

```
public ObservableCollection<Centro> Centros { get; set; }
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Puedes mostrar exactamente donde es que  te lanza el error?

Comment: Gracias por contestar @Einer .
No da ninguna información, solo pone que es en UserPage.xaml. https://imgur.com/hgJ4nfH
Buscando tampoco encuentro nada ni nadie parecido al que le haya dado este error.

Comment: Busca el stacktrace del error que dará más información.

Comment: En este caso no da nada más de información:

1>------ Operación Compilar iniciada: proyecto: Alvac.Android, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
2>----- Operación Compilar omitida: proyecto: Alvac.iOS, configuración: Debug iPhone -----
2>Proyecto no seleccionado para compilarse para esta configuración de solución
3>------ Operación Compilar omitida: proyecto: Alvac.UWP, configuración: Debug x86 ------
3>Proyecto no seleccionado para compilarse para esta configuración de solución
1>C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Alvac\Alvac\Alvac\Pages\UserPage.xaml : error : La secuencia no contiene elementos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está solucionado, el error estaba en el uso de dos StackLayout dentro de un mismo ContentPage.
El error que daba no tiene nada que ver, pero bueno, qué se le va a hacer.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.